# System.NullReferenceException: ... in C#

Tags: c#, reflection

Here's the code:

```
foreach (var property in this.allProperties)
        {
            var propertyItself = element.GetType().GetProperty(property.GetType().Name);

            if (propertyItself.PropertyType != typeof(Int32)) // Here I get System.NullReferenceException: Object reference not set to an instance of an object
            { continue; }

            if ((int)propertyItself.GetValue(element, null) == 0)
            { return false; }
        }
```

I can't figure this out. If any one can or understand what is going on, please help us! Thanks in advance!!!

Comment: You have a null reference exception.... That's what's wrong. Without a stack trace or some context there is no way for us to see what's wrong.

Comment: Attach a debugger and investigate. `propertyItself` is likely null.

Comment: Whenever I have a null reference exception I call CSI. :) Horatio solves all my problems in no time. Hehehe...

Comment: propertyItself is null

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `propertyItself` variable is null.

That means that this call is somehow incorrect:

```
element.GetType().GetProperty(property.GetType().Name);
```

I'm just guessing, but I bet this code `property.GetType().Name` should be `property.ToString()` or `property.Name` if that is an option.

What you're passing in is the name of the Type of the `property`, not its `Name`.

Comment: Good observation. I will try smething over your view point. [Edited] It worked! Fantasctic! Awesome!!! Thanks @canhazbits.

Answer (score 0):

Without any debugger info there is no way to give a specific answer to what is wrong.

Try putting

```
if(propertyIteself!=null && propertyIteslef.PropertyType!=null && propertyItself.PropertyType != typeof(Int32)) 
 { continue; }
```

This will null check both items that could possibly be blowing up on that line.

or try this

```
        foreach (var property in this.allProperties)
        {
          var propertyItself = element.GetType().GetProperty(property.GetType().Name);
          if(propertyItself!=null && propertyItself.PropertyType!=null)
           {
                if (propertyItself.PropertyType != typeof(Int32)) 
                { continue; }

                if ((int)propertyItself.GetValue(element, null) == 0)
                 { return false; }
            }
         }
```

Comment: yeah, ok! I will try that way out and post the stack trace too. Thanks!